# Deleting variable assignments in a sub-notebook which is called from my main notebook

Tags: scoping, clear, code-organization

I have two notebooks; one main notebook which calls another notebook several times in a loop. I want to delete the assignments of variables in the sub-notebook which is called from the main one.

Using `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` in the sub-notebook also clears the main notebook variable assignments, which I want to protect; I just want to clear the assignments in the sub-notebook.

How could I solve this?

Comment: I strongly recommend to convert your notebook to a function e.g. `proc1[]: = Module[{localvariables...}, ...]`. You will have more flexibility and no questions like this anymore.

Comment: @Kuba Will I write the procedure proc1[] into the notebook cell or elsewhere ? The problem is I use notebooks since it allows to use mathematical superscript and subscripts, which makes the calculations easy to follow and while writing a procedure in a .m script; could I use Basic Math Assistant Pallette ?

Comment: You can define it in a notebook, no problem. Just be sure to evaluate this definition in a fresh session.

Comment: This is a good start `tutorial/DefiningFunctions`

Comment: You could write a function that clears the relevant variables.

Comment: Set the default [`CellContext`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellContext.html) for the notebooks to `Notebook`.  Any variables that you need in ``Global` `` then explicitly set with the context name, e.g. ``Global`x = 2``.